# Undefined for type ArrayList - putting random object of arraylist into variable

Tags: java, variables, arraylist, types, undefined

I am attempting to place a randomly chosen object of my ArrayList into a variable in the class constructor.

```
public WordsToGuess randomWord()
    {
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(words.size());
        WordsToGuess chosenWord = words.get(index);
        return chosenWord;
    }

public Model() throws IOException
    {
        words = new ArrayList<WordsToGuess>();
        chosenWord = words.randomWord();
        randomGenerator = new Random();
        }
```

I get an error saying "The method randomWord() is undefined for the type ArrayList". I have removed unnecessary code from the constructor.

Comment: Why is this -1? Anubian managed to solve it so it's not really off-topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chosenWord = words.randomWord();
```

Should read:

```
chosenWord = randomWord();
```

`randomWord()` is not a method of ArrayList but of your class.

Comment: "Type mismatch = cannot convert from WordsToGuess to String" :(

Comment: chosenWord should be an object of type WordsToGuess not a String.

Comment: This has fixed the error. I will sort out another error I have run into and hope there is no runtime error. Thanks for the mean time!

Comment: If one of your answers helped you, either mine or Bohemians, accept it.

Comment: Was going to soon. :) Just checking other things at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `randomWord()` method seems to be a local instance method. Try this instead:

```
chosenWord = randomWord();
```

I will add that your design might need some tidying up. It seems your methods have a muddled purpose: Try to keep each method's task as small and focused as possible.

Comment: "Type mismatch = cannot convert from WordsToGuess to String" :(

Comment: I mean even then .. the code is gibberish as it won't do anything.

Comment: What type does `words` store?

Comment: It is all part of a hangman application. I have removed a LOT of other code. This is the code that is relevant to the occurring error.

Comment: Strings loaded from a file.

Comment: then this line `WordsToGuess chosenWord = words.get(index);` won't compile, which makes your question "unanswerable"

Comment: Solved by Anubian. Thanks for trying :)